# unable to import pycryptodome in django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pycryptodome

I have created a django-project called **dp1** and inside that I have made a djano-app called **da1**.
I am working on Windows inside a virtual env named testing.

**da1\views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import os

class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.block_size = AES.block_size
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        plain_text = self.__pad(plain_text)
        iv = Random.new().read(self.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain_text.encode())
        return b64encode(iv + encrypted_text).decode("utf-8")

    def decrypt(self, encrypted_text):
        encrypted_text = b64decode(encrypted_text)
        iv = encrypted_text[:self.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plain_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text[self.block_size:]).decode("utf-8")
        return self.__unpad(plain_text)

    def __pad(self, plain_text):
        number_of_bytes_to_pad = self.block_size - len(plain_text) % self.block_size
        ascii_string = chr(number_of_bytes_to_pad)
        padding_str = number_of_bytes_to_pad * ascii_string
        padded_plain_text = plain_text + padding_str
        return padded_plain_text

    @staticmethod
    def __unpad(plain_text):
        last_character = plain_text[len(plain_text) - 1:]
        return plain_text[:-ord(last_character)]
# Create your views here.

def home(req):
    return render(req,'home.html',{"name":"Manish"})

def add(req):
    choice = req.POST['choice'] # value of selected radio button
    val1 = req.POST['text1']
    val2 = req.POST['text2']
    result = choice+val1+val2
    key_128 = "kuch bhi"
    iv = "InitializationVe"
    aesCipher = AESCipher(key_128)
    print(aesCipher.key)
    sentence = "manish swami"
    print(aesCipher.encrypt(sentence))
    return render(req, 'result.html' ,{'result': result})
```

`from Crypto.Cipher import AES` I am getting a error `Import "Crypto.Cipher" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)`.

I have installed the pycryptodome module inside the virtual env but still the error is coming.[image]

The link to the package pycrytodome is → https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/installation.html
I tried doing the test-everything command `python -m Crypto.SelfTest` but it was only working in global.

I installed this package in Global Env and also in Virtual env but In virtual it is not working whereas in global it is working fine.

This is the global app:

```
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import os


class AESCipher(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.block_size = AES.block_size
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode()).digest()

    def encrypt(self, plain_text):
        plain_text = self.__pad(plain_text)
        iv = Random.new().read(self.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt(plain_text.encode())
        return b64encode(iv + encrypted_text).decode("utf-8")

    def decrypt(self, encrypted_text):
        encrypted_text = b64decode(encrypted_text)
        iv = encrypted_text[:self.block_size]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        plain_text = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_text[self.block_size:]).decode("utf-8")
        return self.__unpad(plain_text)

    def __pad(self, plain_text):
        number_of_bytes_to_pad = self.block_size - len(plain_text) % self.block_size
        ascii_string = chr(number_of_bytes_to_pad)
        padding_str = number_of_bytes_to_pad * ascii_string
        padded_plain_text = plain_text + padding_str
        return padded_plain_text

    @staticmethod
    def __unpad(plain_text):
        last_character = plain_text[len(plain_text) - 1:]
        return plain_text[:-ord(last_character)]

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    print("hello")
    key_128 = "samplekey"
    iv = "InitializationVe"
    aesCipher = AESCipher(key_128)
    print(aesCipher.key)
    sentence = "inputsentence"
    print(aesCipher.encrypt(sentence))
    print(aesCipher.decrypt(aesCipher.encrypt(sentence)))
```

Comment: Have you tried `pycrypto` package installation?

Comment: @SuyogShimpi ya .. but its not working for some reason

Comment: It looks like an installation problem, have you tried to reinstall it? And 'python -m Crypto.SelfTest' command can help you to test the installation completeness of it, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the folder 'crypto' in virtual env's site-packages folder to 'Crypto' resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use docker, after add 'pycryptodome==3.11.0' in the requirements, then rebuild, ran into the same problem.

I guess the image have caches.

After clear history images, solve that error.

Hereby leave a msg for sharing...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30322217)